# Why $\lim_{x\to + \infty} x^a = + \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $ x^a$, $a > 0$.

Considering the sequences in $(0,\infty) $:

$$a_n = e^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

$$b_n = e^{-n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

We know that: $$\lim (a_n) = \infty$$ 
 $$\lim (b_n) = 0$$

Since $a > 0$ then:

$\lim({a_n}^a) = lim((e^a)^n) = +\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to + \infty} x^a = + \infty$

Note: $e^a \ge e^0 = 1$ $ $ since $ $ $a > 0$

What is the reason for this last implication?

Comment: $x^a$ is an increasing function and For any $A>0$ you have that $x^a>A$ if $x>N=A^{1/a}$.

Comment: @csch2 Your comment is valid *in general*, but here $f(x)=x^a$ is increasing, so yes, a single sequence is enough.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut 
What proposition are you relying on to say that a sequence is sufficient so that the limit is also sufficient?

Comment: Not a specific proposition. It's not difficult to prove with $\epsilon-\delta$ that if $f$ is increasing on $(0,+\infty)$, and if the sequence $a_n$ is such that $a_n\to\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)$ exists iff and $f(a_n)$ is bounded, and likewise $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+\infty$ iff $a_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: I meant "iff $f(a_n)$ is unbounded", at the end of the previous comment.